# How to rename files from old to new from csv file using python?

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system, rename, file-rename

I have a CSV file which has two columns:

```
Filename_Old               |  Filename_New

Jean1_Aspect_Six.jpg       |  Jean1_Aspect_Six_New.jpg       
Jean2_Aspect_Five.jpg      |  Jean2_Aspect_Ratio_TN.jpg 
Jean1_Table_P2.jpg         |  Jean1_Table_TN.jpg
Jas_Snail_P3.png           |  Jas_P3_TN.png
```

I have more than a thousand pictures which I need to rename using this method. Can this be done using python? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` to iterate over pairs of corresponding items:

```
import os

for old, new in zip(df['Filename_Old'], df['Filename_New']):
    os.rename(old, new)
```

As you are batch processing a large number of files, it might also be worth doing a `try` so that if one of the renames fails (e.g. one of the files was already renamed), it doesn't stop the whole operation.  For example:

```
for old, new in zip(df['Filename_Old'], df['Filename_New']):
    try:
        os.rename(old, new)
    except OSError as exc:
        print(f'WARNING: could not rename {old} to {new}: {exc}')
    else:
        print(f'renamed {old} to {new}')
```

---

Note that I am taking your question to mean the raw contents of your CSV file looks like:

```
Filename_Old,Filename_New
Jean1_Aspect_Six.jpg,Jean1_Aspect_Six_New.jpg       
Jean2_Aspect_Five.jpg,Jean2_Aspect_Ratio_TN.jpg 
Jean1_Table_P2.jpg,Jean1_Table_TN.jpg
Jas_Snail_P3.png,Jas_P3_TN.png
```

and that you have read it in using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv")
```